# Converting .cs class file to .dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, c#

I am trying to convert the famous BingSearchContainer.cs class file to .dll so that I can use it in a vb.net project. I have read and followed every single step mentioned in here

http://footyntech.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/creating-and-using-dll-files/

however when I compile it gives me several errors shown in the bottom screenshot
[image]

I also tried to change the .NET Framework from 3.5 to 4.0 and vise versa, but without luck.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Comment: Look for the relevent types in the file listed at the line numbers listed.  Either you are missing a `using` for those types, you haven't included one or more files that are needed, you're missing a reference, etc.  The error is rather...self explanatory.  It's also generally easier to deal with such errors in an IDE, but to each their own.

Comment: Ummmm: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: You need to specify the reference the System.Data.Services dll. I'd also recommend using an IDE.

Comment: If you really want to go CSC way at least read help: `csc /?` to know what other things you can specify. But really using IDE to do so (steps are shown in @erich007 answer) is so much easier, and even if you need command line build - building .csproj with MSBUILD is as impressive for bystanders as manually specifying CSC arguments.

Comment: The error tells you what you are missing.. one of your Services is missing the using System.Data; in the header try adding that and if it's there already ..try adding it to the reference in the project read the reference link using csc here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to reference the required assemblies used by your code, e.g. System.Data.dll. With the command line Compiler you do that with the switch /r

```
csc /target:library /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Data.Services.Client.dll /out:Student.dll BingSearchContainer.cs
```

For every data type that is missing you have to check in the MSDN in which assembly this data type is and add it to the list.

Comment: or you can use this for your full answer for the OP 
`csc /target:library /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Data.Services.Client /out:Student.dll BingSearchContainer.cs `

Answer (score 2):

From this article:
http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2012/07/04/integrate-bing-search-api-to-asp-net-application.aspx

It looks to me like you're missing this part:

> To build the code file you need to add reference to the following
>   library. System.Data.Services.Client

On my system at least, this assembly is located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Services.Client.dll

So you will need to go get System.Data.Services.Client from there and copy it to your local build folder. Then add `/reference:System.Data.Services.Client` to your command line for csc. Or, of course, just use Visual Studio and use the .NET tab of "Add Reference..." for the project to add a reference to System.Data.Services.Client.